# I cannot access drupal.org

Tags: community-official-site

I haven't been able to access drupal.org for the past few days. When using Chrome I get: 'This webpage is not available'.  I have no problems with accessing any other site.

Oddly enough when I use a proxy I have no problem. I've cleared my cache in both IE and chrome but still no luck. I don't believe my IP address has been blacklisted so beyond that I don't know. This is true when I try on my phone too so perhaps it is IP address related?

Comment: I believe your question should moved to another SE website; not sure which one exactly though. This is probably a problem with your ISP - running a traceroute command should give you some hints.

Comment: Should have asked this is the first place:  What does: "I haven't been able to access drupal.org" mean?  Do you get "access denied", do you get "unroutable addess", do you get the WSOD, or is the nature of non-access something else?

Comment: Free Radical - when using Chrome I get 'This webpage is not available' - As for taking this elsewhere I thought that drupal.stackexchange could help since it's specific to Drupal - I have no problems with any other site.

Comment: It happened to me too, when I was in the USA: I could just access drupal.org from a proxy.

Comment: If the problem is about Chrome, then it is off-topic here.

Comment: I don't think it's about Chrome. I can't access it via IE or safari either. You seem determined to make this off-topic. The only site I have a problem with is drupal.org

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth here is a link to [Chromebook help](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/1085581) for "This webpage is not available".

Assuming you've typed in the right URL, it looks like Chrome will give you this error message if it thinks the site takes too long to respond.  The help page also suggests:

- Clear your cookies.
- Adjust your proxy settings

You could also try to use another browser to access the site (both Firefox and MSIE work OK for me).

Comment: V interesting - looks like you have to be logged in to get a straight up "Access Denied" for the whitelist page, otherwise you get the login form. Actually I guess that's essentially the same thing

Comment: Interesting indeed - if I can't get into Drupal.org how can i get into http://drupal.org/httpbl/whitelist

Comment: ....oops hit enter too fast. Anyway, I did get in using a proxy and when I entered http://drupal.org/httpbl/whitelist I did get Access Denied which means I'm NOT blacklisted. So I'm back to square one. It would seem that it's IP related?